# Validate FTP credentials

Tags: php, linux, ftp

I am writing a PHP page, which stores FTP Account's address, Username and Password.

I need to validate them against the server and tell user if the credentials provided are working.

It is possible to fire system commands, System commands are preferable so that a reusable script could be written.

So can anybody tell me how do I validate the ftp credentials on bash? I am CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ftp_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php) and [ftp_login()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php) :

```
<?php

$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$result = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if ((!$conn) || (!result)) {
    echo "Failed";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}

ftp_close($conn);
```

Comment: You've got a tiny error in your code. The variable $result is missing the $ when used in the if-condition. It should read !$result. Other than that great solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function testFtpCredentials($server, $username, $password){
    if(!is_string($server) or !strlen($server = trim($server))){
        return null;
    }
    if(!is_string($username) or !strlen($username = trim($username))){
        return null;
    }
    if(!is_string($password) or !strlen($password = trim($password))){
        return null;
    }
    if(!$connection = ftp_connect($server)){
        return false;
    }
    $result = ftp_login($connection, $username, $password);
    ftp_close($connection);
    return (bool)$result;
}

// How to use it.
var_dump(testFtpCredentials('ftp.server', 'username', 'password'));
?>
```

**A function. Use it! Don't do system calls for such easy task.**

Comment: "Easy" depends on the setup. Maybe the target FTP server supports only active mode, or only passive mode? Maybe the local server is firewalled and the passive mode ports are restricted to a certain range, or it can only access other systems via an FTP proxy? Such an "easy" task then is easier to do with a command line FTP client which can be configured accordingly.

Comment: @Shi **What does Active/Passive mode has to do with login test?** That's all about data *(file, listing)* transfers. Seriously?! Learn the FTP protocol, see how connections work and how file transfers work and you'll understand where things can get passive... #facepalm

Comment: Okay, you are right. Still, the FTP proxy part still holds. And as we are in a flaming mood; what about muting `ftp_connect()` and `ftp_login()`? As the return code is properly checked, there is no need to fill the PHP log with warnings. I just skip the part about "do not write or propose code that fills the log with useless because handled warnings!" And this all-fitting function does not check the existence of the optional FTP extension. Not that easy I guess.

Comment: @Shi Muting errors is the devs choice. It's all about how they manage their error log. Maybe they'll find the meaningful. I never mute errors by hand, I control the INI settings. I have yet to find a host without the FTP extension. It's just one of those cases where, if it's missing, you can find another host. And you also figure out quickly that it's missing. **PS**: *If I were to flame, I'd say you name misses a `T`.* But I'm in no flaming mood. It's a beautiful Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Has an [FTP Module](https://www.php.net/ftp) you can use to validate the credentials

Basic example from the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ftp.examples-basic.php)

```
<?php
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
?>
```

Of course, if you really want to FTP on the command line via exec() or something, there are resources like [these docs](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_ftp.htm) which will help.

A working example I just tried:

file: ftp.sh

```
#! /bin/bash

USER=user@domain.com
PASS=xxxxxxxxxxxx

ftp -inv domain.com <<EOF
user $USER $PASS

ls -l
```

file: index.php

```
$result = shell_exec('sh ftp.sh');
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
try {
        $con = ftp_connect($server);
        if (false === $con) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
        }

        $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
        if (true === $loggedIn) {
            echo 'Success!';
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
        }

        print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
        ftp_close($con);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```